# JTable+mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, jtable

I would like to save information entered on jtable to mysql database. I'm specifically saving students' marks into the database from jtable. here is a snippet of my code that's supposed to save the items by clicking the "save" button on the gui.

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                                                                               
  tblMarkSheet.getRowCount();
      try 
      { 

        String sql = "INSERT INTO marksheet(examName,streamName,className,termName,academicYear,pupilID,mathematics,english,kiswahili,science,SS_CRE,total) VALUES('" + cboExamName.getSelectedItem() + "','" + cboStream.getSelectedItem() + "','" + cboClass.getSelectedItem() + "','" + cboTerm.getSelectedItem() + "','" + cboAcademicYear.getSelectedItem() + "','" + Integer.parseInt(tblMarkSheet.getValueAt(row, 0).toString()) + "','" + Integer.parseInt(tblMarkSheet.getValueAt(row, 1).toString()) + "','" + Integer.parseInt(tblMarkSheet.getValueAt(row, 2).toString()) + "','" + Integer.parseInt(tblMarkSheet.getValueAt(row, 3).toString()) + "','" + Integer.parseInt(tblMarkSheet.getValueAt(row, 4).toString()) + "','" + Integer.parseInt(tblMarkSheet.getValueAt(row, 5).toString()) + "','" + Integer.parseInt(tblMarkSheet.getValueAt(row, 6).toString()) + "') ";
        stmt.execute(sql);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Marks Saved successfully!");

      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at AmsProject.MarkSheet.btnSaveActionPerformed(MarkSheet.java:445)
    at AmsProject.MarkSheet.access$100(MarkSheet.java:18)
    at AmsProject.MarkSheet$3.actionPerformed(MarkSheet.java:185)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I wish I could paste my code here with the line numbers but my IDE has issues with showing the numbers. Line 445 is this

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(tblMarkSheet.getValueAt(row, 6).toString()));
```

line 18:

```
public class MarkSheet extends javax.swing.JFrame {
```

and line 185:

```
btnSaveActionPerformed(evt);
```

Please help me out. I'll be more than grateful!

Comment: Where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: saving into the database. I'm unable to get rid of the null pointer exception

Comment: Please reformat your code, the `INSERT` line is far far too long. Then re-run the code and give us the surrounding lines and trim the stack trace to the lines that are actually yours.

Comment: _btnSaveActionPerformed_ check whether you have initialized this variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Statement#executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) for database write operations. Also use `PreparedStatement` rather than `Statement` to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

From your update the variable `tblMarkSheet` appears to be `null`:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(tblMarkSheet.getValueAt(row, 6).toString()))
```

Check that this has been assigned correctly and is available in the scope of the `actionPerformed` method. Ensure, for instance, that you are not creating a local instance of this variable where it is instantiated.

Comment: Hey Reimus, thanks for the help. I've made the corrections you've suggested but I'm still getting the null pointer exception

Comment: We don't have access to your program or your data. We have no idea what the line numbers of the Exception message refer to. So you need to determine yourself which variable is null and why it is null.

Comment: @ImaniKarimiMbogo At a glance I would suggest that the stmt is null. Best to crack open your IDE's debugger and attach a break point to the line that is causing you the exception and check all the variables on it

Comment: @MadProgrammer The OP has indicated the line causing the `NPE` and `tblMarkSheet` is the only effective variable in play. Ofc, without seeing the rest of the code can't be definite...

Comment: @Reimeus technically, it also be the table model or value returned from the table. Best solution is still to debug the program. But you are right, still not enough information to do anything but guess

Comment: I've decided to use jtextfields instead. thanks for the response though